# PostgreSQL How to use a CSV in a query

Tags: postgresql, csv, declare

Ok I am very new to postgres so bear with me. I have been using the string_agg function in postgres to get my CSV. I want to know how to use my CSV in a query. I did this in SQL server by using a DECLARE but as I have read there is not a way to DECLARE globally in postgres. Any help, documentation, examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be honest i don't know what you're trying to achive. I don't see correlation between `string_agg` and `DECLARE`. Do you want to create CSV? or process given file? or do you just look for `DECLARE` equivalent? What have you done yet and what's your particular problem?

Comment: I guess I should clarify. I want to use string_agg like a CSV (Comma Sperated Value). So when I use it I can get a listing of lets say recordIDs. Now I want to use the that list in a function.

Comment: A very simple example of this would be running a string_agg to get all recordIDs that are less than 100. Then write a query 'code' Select * From Table1 Where recordID(string_agg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so based on your question and your comment. PostgreSQL has `ARRAY` type which fits nicely in SQL statements, so you can make an array from your CSV-string and use it in queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE record_id = ANY(string_to_array( string_agg , ','));
```

Actually there is no need to use CSV at all. If you have such option change to use `array_agg` in the first place (instead of `string_agg`).

Function `string_to_array(text, delimiter)` splits string into array with delimiter passed as an argument. Expression `record_id = ANY( array )` returns `TRUE` when "any" of the array elements is equal to `record_id` and `FALSE` otherwise.